# Problem with IPhone app Loacalization

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4

I am developing an application for IPhone, and it need to be Localized for english (easy enough) and portuguese. My doubt is if we can only set the Localization for the xib files or if we can add the .m files to the localization too, because the .m files are always in the english version, while the Xib files are working as they should...
BEst regards.
Ps. I am Using XCode 4..

Answer (score 0):

I can think of only one localizable resource in source code - strings. For these you have several variants of `NSLocalizedString`. Take a look at this manual [Internationalization Programming Topics](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/BPInternational.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can localize the xibs fairly easily, you should also look at

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] localizedStringForKey:Value:Table: ];
```

you can use this to pull the required string from the strings file, 
which once you have generated you can manage with tools from http://www.loc-suite.org/
they make ongoing development and localization much easier.